# how to make Gmail type conversation view

Tags: jquery, gmail

- I want to view the messages list like gmail conversation.
- where the look is like accordion,
- multiple messages can be viewed by clicking on them,
- if more messages are there like 5 or more, then the view should be
  collapsed like 'older messages'
- **how is this possible via jQuery or anything else is better for this.
  Give some hint/help to let me proceed please**

[image: http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/550/2229870852.jpg]

Comment: I wonder why you tagged this PHP? It has absolutely nothing to do with PHP. Google jQuery accordion and start from there.

Comment: but i dont think it is accordian, as it is displaying 'xyz older messages' in between, which is not possible in jQuery accordian,
is it possible? I am not at all sure, please guide some morw

Comment: As BenM said in his very useful response below, nobody here will write the code for you. The 'xyz older messages' can be the title of the accordion when collapsed, or something like a floating layer above the collapsed accordion. The accordion is a good place to START from. Good luck!

Comment: i didnt demand code.
just wanted to know tht is it possible via accordian or gmail is using ui-accordion or not.

Thanx.

Comment: Didnt understand why negative marking.

Comment: (a) It's definitely a form of accordion, but a lot of work has gone into it to make it look like that in Gmail. (b) I guess the downvotes are maybe because S/O users didn't think it's a useful question and maybe because you tagged it PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is certainly possible through jQuery. However, there are a number of ways to implement this functionality, some more straightforward than others.

The first option is to simply load all of the messages when the page loads, and then hide everything except the last one. You can then use jQuery to show it when the use clicks. However, this is very inefficient, since it will slow down the initial load time. The [**accordion found here**](http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/VPfJ5/3/) ([credit](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-jquery-accordion/)) is a good starting point to look at. Here's the jQuery code:

```
(function($) {

  var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();

  $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
    allPanels.slideUp();
    $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
    return false;
  });

})(jQuery);
```

The better option would be to load the basic data for previous messages (date, sender and subject), and then use AJAX to fetch the whole content when the user clicks on a message. This is a much better approach, as you're only requesting the data when it's needed. You can read more about using AJAX within jQuery in their [**API Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

This should give you a starting point to work from. You should be advised though, that SO isn't a drive-thru code generator. It is for asking specific questions relating to programming problems. With the information above, you should do some research, have a go at putting it together, and if / when you run into problems, ask over here. Be sure to include your code and a very good description of the problem and desired outcome.

Comment: +1 for Chris Coyier's example.